# Как добавить в готовый (унаследованный) fieldsets поле Django?

Tags: python, django

fieldsets #1
[image: fieldsets #1]

---

fieldsets #2

[image: fieldsets #2]

---

Нужно что бы поля из fieldsets #1 были в fieldsets #2

---

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Полагаю, что вам нужно изменить название данного класса (например, на ExtendedUserAdmin) - сейчас получается, что вы его наследуете от самого себя, да ещё и модель используете с тем же именем.

Comment: я его наследую не от самого себя, а от from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
и ничего плохого в этом не вижу

Comment: Конечно я могу использовать from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin as AnyNameUserAdmin
но я думаю, что так будет большей путаницы в классах